# AWT - testing existing applet

Tags: java, testing, applet, awt, fest

I need to test Java Applet written in AWT for browsers, but I don't know how to connect to existing frame/dialog/button.
Is any option to get list of existing AWT object in system, and do something with them?
I tried with FEST-AWT, but if I understand correctly, he only allow to create new objects and do things on them.

Answer (score 0):

I have only written one applet in the browser with AWT. What i did was whipped up a basic XHTML document and used the "applet" tag. You put this in the same directory as your .java applet, passing it the arguement code="InitClass.class" (double check that is the right name for the arguement). From there, you compile your applet in your IDE and then open your html doc in your browser. **applet tag was deprrcated in HTML4**

Comment: *"applet tag was removed in HTML5"*  Really?  It was [deprecated in HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.4) but exactly how do you 'remove' an element?  Browsers still understand the applet tag, BTW - it is not going away anytime soon.

Comment: I can't run this applet on my IDE. That application is rly huge, and I have to use it on test environment. My only option is go to that website(using selenium) and when applet appears(select file form) I have to insert string with location and click OK.

Comment: Well, you don't need to run it. You just have to compile it. Essentially, you need to get your .class files.